# Open AI Assistant Api Files "Too many tokens"

Tags: artificial-intelligence, openai-api

According to the documentation for the Open AI Assistant API:

> The size of individual files can be a maximum of 512 MB or 2 million tokens for Assistants

I am currently trying to include a file that is 1.3 Million tokens (about 6 mb) and the response back from OpenAI's API is:

```
Failed to update assistant: UserError: Failed to index file: Error extracting text from file  

file-*** detail_str=',detail: File contains too may tokens. Max allowed tokens per file is 2000000
```

I have run my file through the OpenAI Tokenizer as well as tiktoken and can confirm that it gives me 1.3 Million tokens.

- I'm using the `cl100k_base` encoder with `gpt-3-5-turbo-1106` to count my own tokens
- My file is purely text.

What would be causing this to happen?